# Simple mod rewrite with PHP Get values

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

can someone tell me what in the world I'm doing wrong?

trying to take:

```
search.php?key=23&category=testing
```

and make:

```
/23/testing.html
```

with this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?key=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

For the life of me I can't figure this out...or if there is a better way, please point me in the right direction.

** UPDATE

Ok, after giving up on this I finally contacted the hosting company to see if there was a problem with my domain that was keeping this from working.  Here is what they told me:

> 1. You do not have a rewrite condition and you only have a simple rewrite. For the code to >always work properly you should normally set a "RewriteCond" with a valid pattern.
> 2. You have used the "?" question mark character in your code although this is an escape >character and doing so would only cause a rewrite to index.php based upon your code as >everything after the question mark gets escaped.
>
> Please consider using a "RewriteCond" in your code and also use regexes to properly escape >the "?" character and avoid unexpected behavior.

Can anyone give me some help?  Thanks!

Comment: make sure to put R in the arguments [L,R]. I usually build a quick custom MVC and make every request go through index.php. that way i can script out my permalinks.

Comment: still no dice.  I don't have to do anything else with my PHP files do I?  I can get a simple hmtl redirect to work, so I know the path, etc is working...but for the life of me I can't figure out why this won't work..

Comment: the rewrite rule should start with ^/ i believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?key=$1&category=$2 [L,R]
```